# How to avoid the aspx.designer files when creating new webforms in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I found some times aspx.designer file creating and some times not. Can you guys let me know where to set the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you create web site projects, not web application projects.
If you create web site projects, no designer.cs files will be generated.
For the difference between web site projects and web application projects see [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)